# remove whitespaces from jaxb xml response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache-axis

I have a `WS` that generates a `SOAP` `XML` message. Due to size limitations I would like to remove the unnecessary whitespaces (used for indentation) and new lines. How can I do this when using generated classes and annotations (`@WebService` and `@WebMethod`)? In the examples I have seen it is done like this:

```
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);
```

However, I am not manually creating the `Marshaller` so I do not know where I can add this property and if this is the correct way of doing it. The `JAXB` implementation is `axis2`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom JAXBContext and annotate your webservice as mentioned below:

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "Hello")
    @UsesJAXBContext(value = CustomJaxbContext.class)
    public class HelloWS
    {   ...
    }

    public class HelloJaxbContext implements JAXBContextFactory
    {
      @Override
      public JAXBRIContext createJAXBContext(SEIModel seim, List<Class> classesToBind, List<TypeReference> typeReferences) throws JAXBException {
          //JAXBRIContext extends JAXBContext, so you should be able to set the desired marshaller properties
          //create your jaxb context with necessary properties for marshalling
          return yourJAXBRIContext;
       }  
    }
```

Refer http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/developer/JAXBContextFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

`<dataFormats><jaxb prettyPrint=false></dataFormats>`This pretty Print flag will format the xml file in compressed way and remove crlf